# Vivaldi: Stabat Mater (Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre) lyrics

Tags: classical-music, lyrics, opera

What is an accurate translation of the lyrics in Larghetto & Andante Molto - Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre? from  Stabat Mater.

I was unable to find a translation and google translator seemed pretty bad^^.

Comment: The cantata ''Cessate, Omai cessate" (RV684) containing "Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre"  isn't the "Stabat Mater" (RV621). Finding translations of Stabat Mater is easy (there are several at https://www.stabatmater.info/english-translation/) since it is part of the Catholic liturgy, but a good translation of a "random" secular cantata might be harder to track down!

Comment: @alephzero ok. but the track is in Vivaldis Sabat Mater. So the lyrics for Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre are not in Sabat Mater?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the track is in Vivaldis Sabat Mater." Do you mean it's a track on some CD that happens to be *called*"Vivaldi's Stabat Mater" or something like that? It's not in the copy of the *score* of RV621 that I have! Anyway, here's a translation of "Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre": http://www.resonusclassics.com/freedownload/RES10115_booklet_300dpi.pdf (see page 6).

Comment: Stabat mater text is in *Latin*. Your aria title is definitely *Italian*, so no match on language level. Borrowing arias is occasionally done for operas, but I can't imagine the move twowards a religious work. So the question title is already inconsistent.

Comment: @alephzero ah now i get it . it's from RV684.

Comment: @alephzero thanks for the link that was wat i was looking for. @ guidot if you say so.

Comment: @alephzero, if you have an answer it would be nice to write it in the answer section. And also I would suggest to write the actual answer instead of a link because links can die.

Answer (score 2):

*[@alephzero](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/2658/alephzero) has provided the [relevant](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/vivaldi-stabat-mater-ah-chinfelice-sempre-lyrics#comment9636_6960) [links](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/vivaldi-stabat-mater-ah-chinfelice-sempre-lyrics#comment9638_6960) in the comments, and I'm just creating an answer here for completeness.*

---

The cantata *Cessate, Omai cessate* (RV684) containing *Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre* isn't the *Stabat Mater* (RV621). Finding translations of *Stabat Mater* is easy, [there are several here](https://www.stabatmater.info/english-translation/), for instance.

For a translation of *Ah Ch'Infelice Sempre*, you can [take a look here](https://www.resonusclassics.com/freedownload/RES10115_booklet_300dpi.pdf). I've copied the relevant parts of the document below for ease of reference.

> *Ah, ch'infelice sempre
>
> mi vuol Dorilla ingrata,
>
> ah, sempre più spietata
>
> m'astringe a lagrimar.*
>
> Ah, ungrateful Dorilla
> wants me to continue suffering;
> ah, always more unmercifully
> she induces my tears
>
> *Per me non v'è ristoro,
>
> per me non v'è più spene.
>
> E il fier martoro e le mie pene,
>
> solo la morte può consolar.*
>
> For me there is no cure,
> for me no more hope.
> Only death will quench
> my pain and sadness.